# Android - set visibility to FAB button in BottomSheet from within a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I need to control a `Floating action button` visibility that is situated in a `BottomSheet` from within a `Fragment` class but when I try to set it's visibility I get this error message:

> VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

**This is what I have in my Fragment class:**

```
private FloatingActionButton fabUpdateInfo;

fabUpdateInfo = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_update);

fabUpdateInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE); //This is where the error message gets triggered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use:

```
fabUpdateInfo.hide();
//or
fabUpdateInfo.show();
```

Instead of:

```
fabUpdateInfo.setVisibility();
```